# Iterate through ranges of elements in a list in Python

Tags: python

I am a beginner in Python and I have a doubt about iterating through a range of elements in a list.

I have this list:

```
['0.95', '0.05', '0.94', '0.06', '0.29', '0.71', '0.001', '0.999']
```

Suppose that, starting in the first position, I want to iterate through ranges of two elements: substituting the first two, leaving the next two as they were, and then substituting again the next two:

```
[-, -, '0.94', '0.06', -, -, '0.001', '0.999']
```

I also want to be able to start at any position. For example, using the same range as before, but starting in the third position:

```
['0.95', '0.05', -, -, '0.29', '0.71', -, -]
```

I have tried range with three parameters, but it only substitutes the first position in the range, not all the elements in the range.

Comment: It would be very helpful to show the code of what you tried.

Comment: @BatuDog88, when you say substituting, do you mean substitute them with `-` or, is there something else?

Comment: In fact I pretend to delete those elements (not substituting them), but I have had trouble before deleting elements from a list, as in the next iterations the list size was different and it was not deleting the elements that I wanted, so first I replace those elements and then delete all "-"s from the list. Maybe not very efficient, but it works for me.

Comment: My answer above answers how to replace elements like this in an efficient way. But, if you only want to delete, why not use `a=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
del a[starting_element::4]
del a[starting_element::3]`?

Answer (score 2):

```
l = ['0.95', '0.05', '0.94', '0.06', '0.29', '0.71', '0.001', '0.999']

def subDashes(l, start):
    newL = []
    for index, elem in enumerate(l):
        if index%4 == start or index%4 == start+1:
            newL.append('-')
        else:
            newL.append(elem)
    return newL

>>> subDashes(l, 0)
['-', '-', '0.94', '0.06', '-', '-', '0.001', '0.999']

>>> subDashes(l, 1)
['0.95', '-', '-', '0.06', '0.29', '-', '-', '0.999']

>>> subDashes(l, 2)
['0.95', '0.05', '-', '-', '0.29', '0.71', '-', '-']
```

Comment: Why not just substitute values in `l` so you don't have to create a new list? `l[i] = '-'` and you could remove the `else` clause

Comment: I wasn't sure if they wanted to modify their original list, so I made a new one just in case.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest, and I think the best, way to do this is like this:

```
seq = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]

replace_list= ['-','-','-','-']

seq[::4] = replace_list[::2]
seq[1::4] = replace_list[1::2]

print seq
```

Output:

```
['-', '-', 3, 4, '-', '-', 7, 8]
```

To start in which item to start just do:

```
replace_list= ['-','-','-']

starting_item=3
seq[starting_item::4] = replace_list[::2]
seq[starting_item+1::4] = replace_list[1::2]
```

Note that replace_list has to have the specific number of elements you want to substitute in seq list.

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3, '-', '-', 6, 7, '-']
```

If you want to replace all items always with same value, you can do:

```
starting_item=3

last_part = min((len(seq) - starting_item) % 4, 2)
size = ((len(seq) - starting_item)/4) * 2 + last_part
replace_list= ['-']*size
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace start with the required starting value.

```
l = ['0.95', '0.05', '0.94', '0.06', '0.29', '0.71', '0.001', '0.999']


def dash(l,start):
    for i in range(start,len(l)):
        if (i - start) % 4 == 0 or (i - start) % 4 == 1:
            l[i] = '-'
    return l

print dash(l,start = 2)
```

Comment: This post has been automatically flagged as low-quality because there is no explanation, only code; and will be perhaps deleted if there is no improvement.